# get warning of Matrix Calculation in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, matrix

I am now writing a code to do matrix calculation in Xcode4.3. 
I could build and run the code below, but I always get the warning saying, " Incompatible pointer types passing 'float (*)[3][2]' to parameter of type 'float *' " 
Can someone explain what that means and how I can avoid the warning?

```
    float num1[3][2] = { {1,5},{2,6},{3,7} };
    float num2[3][2] = { {2,2},{2,6},{3,3} }; 
    float resA[3][2];

    vDSP_vadd(&num1, 1, &num2, 1, &resA, 1, 6);

    for (int i = 0; i<3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j<2; j++) {
            NSLog(@"resA[%d][%d]:%f",i,j,resA[i][j]);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically, an array is **not** a pointer, is only decays to a pointer.
If you want to avoid the warning, you can use:

```
         vDSP_vadd(&num1[0][0], 1, &num2[0][0], 1, &resA[0][0], 1, 6);
```